# Numpy n-th odd root including negative values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to calculate the n-th odd root of some numbers in python. Numpy as a cube root function. Using that function I can compute x^(1/3).

```
x = np.linspace(-100,100,100)
np.cbrt(x)
>>> array([-4.64158883, -4.26859722, -3.81571414, -3.21829795, -2.23144317,
    2.23144317,  3.21829795,  3.81571414,  4.26859722,  4.64158883])
```

However, if I want to compute the same thing for other k-th odd roots in a straightforward manner I'm  somewhat stuck. I cannot use np.power directly, not even to compute the cube root:

```
np.power(x,1./3)
>>> array([       nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,
   2.23144317, 3.21829795, 3.81571414, 4.26859722, 4.64158883])

(-100.)**(1./3)
>>> ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
```

I could compute the k-th odd root for the absolute values of x and then change the sign accordingly for the negative entries in x, but I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way. Here is my current solution:

```
def kth_root(x,k):
    if k % 2 != 0:
        res = np.power(np.abs(x),1./k)
        return res*np.sign(x)
    else:
        return np.power(np.abs(x),1./k)

kth_root(x,3)
>>> array([-4.64158883, -4.26859722, -3.81571414, -3.21829795, -2.23144317,
    2.23144317,  3.21829795,  3.81571414,  4.26859722,  4.64158883])
```

Comment: [`np.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) is more efficient than `abs(x)/x`. BTW, the reason you need to do this is because general powers are computed using logarithms.

Comment: Are you using Python 2? In Python 3 `print((-100) ** (1/3))  # (2.3207944168063896+4.019733843830847j) `

Comment: @DeepSpace That's not Numpy.

Comment: @PM2Ring I may be missing something but OPs `(-100.)**(1./3)` is also not Numpy ?

Comment: BTW, keep in mind that the `**` operator has precedence over `-`

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 2.7, I'll clarify. np.sign makes sense, thanks @PM2Ring!

Comment: @DeepSpace True, but the question is tagged Numpy, and its title begins with Numpy. So I figure they want to use Numpy. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to respond to my own question with my current solution. This is not to say that there doesn't exist an easier or faster method.

```
def kth_root(x,k):
    if k % 2 != 0:
        res = np.power(np.abs(x),1./k)
        return res*np.sign(x)
    else:
        return np.power(np.abs(x),1./k)


x = np.linspace(-100,100,100)
kth_root(x,3)
>>> array([-4.64158883, -4.26859722, -3.81571414, -3.21829795, -2.23144317,
2.23144317,  3.21829795,  3.81571414,  4.26859722,  4.64158883])
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and, starting from you `def` a defined a function to compute `x` to the power of rational exponent `n/d` with the correct real domain.

```
def r_pow(x, n, d):
    """
    Compute x to the power of n/d (not reduced to lowest
    expression) with the correct function real domains.
    
    ARGS:
        x (int,float,array): base
        n (int)            : exponent numerator
        d (int)            : exponent denominator
        
    RETURNS:
        x to the power of n/d
    """
    
    # list to array
    if type(x) == list:
        x = np.array(x)
    # check inputs
    if type(n) != int or type(d) != int:
        raise Exception("Exponent numerator and denominator must be integers")
    # if denominator is zero
    if not d:
        raise Exception("Exponent denominator cannot be 0")
        
    # raise x to power of n
    X = x**n
    # even denominator
    if not d % 2:
        # domain is for X>=0 only
        if type(x) == np.ndarray:
            X[X<0] = np.nan
        elif X < 0:
            X = np.nan
        res = np.power(X, 1./d)
        return res
    # odd denominator
    else:
        # domain is all R
        res = np.power(np.abs(X), 1./d)
        res *= np.sign(X)
        return res
```

So, for example, we can have x^(2/3), where the domain is all R and the function sign is always positive (because x^2 is always positive)

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x, r_pow(x, 2, 3));
```

[image]

or x^(1/3) where the domain is all R, but the function sign is negative for x<0

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x, r_pow(x, 1, 3));
```

[image]

or x^(1/6) where the real domain is [0, +∞)

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x, r_pow(x, 1, 6));
```

[image]