# Struggling to understand a Runtime Warning for value entered in a power when using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
d = 120
m = 45
x = np.arange(0, d, 1)
y = (m*np.sin((x**(1.1)+30)/(0.7*d))**2.2) - (m*np.sin((2*x**(1.1)+30)/(0.7*d))**2.2)
```

Gives the error:
`running.py:26: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power`
But I don’t understand why this is happening.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's due `0.7**(something large)` converges to zero, so you're dividing by zero.

Comment: When I run the first bracketed section alone (before the subtract sign) it works fine. It seems like the problem you have  suggested is an issue the the second half :/

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> m*np.sin((2*x**(1.1)+30)/(0.7*d))
array([ 15.73194637,  16.73121346,  17.86226504,  19.03958247,
        ...
         6.96013957,   5.16797026,   3.36497969,   1.55409031,
        -0.26174328,  -2.07953935,  -3.8962942 ,  -5.70898742,
        -7.5145872 ,  -9.31005568, -11.09235441, -12.85844979,
       -14.60531859, -16.3299535 , -18.02936862, -19.70060506,
       -21.34073643, -22.9468744 , -24.51617418, -26.04583993,
       -27.53313024, -28.97536339, -30.36992266, -31.71426152,
       -33.0059087 , -34.2424732 , -35.42164915, -36.54122056,
       -37.59906596, -38.59316286, -39.52159205, -40.38254179,
       -41.17431178, -41.89531695, -42.54409109, -43.11929025,
       -43.61969594, -44.04421816, -44.39189813, -44.66191082,
       -44.8535673 , -44.96631676, -44.99974837, -44.95359279,
       -44.8277235 , -44.62215784, -44.33705779, -43.97273045])
>>> _.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

So you're getting a bunch of negative numbers, but raising them to the power `2.2` will give *complex* numbers:

```
>>> (-43.97273045)**2.2
(3333.966245482375+2422.2682642773098j)
>>> (-3.95030853e-07)**2.2
(6.6152442046857145e-15+4.806256247845179e-15j)
```

However, the data type of your array is `float64`, and thus it can't be raised to a power that results in complex numbers:

```
>>> np.float64(-3.95030853e-07)**2.2
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
nan
```

So all the powers for negative numbers become NaN.

You can compute odd roots of negative numbers (you're essentially computing `(thing ** 11) ** (1/5)`) with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491326/numpy-n-th-odd-root-including-negative-values).