# Negative Real Solution of nthroot - Python

Tags: python, numpy, performance, built-in

I am scaling data using the built-in power operation in Python. However, I noticed that when trying to nth-root negative numbers (for odd n), I receive the solution of `x^n = -N` corresponding to `theta = pi/n` which is a Complex solution. Ideally I would receive the negative Real solution `x = (-N)^(1/n)` instead.

Below are the following Built-in and NumPy implementations.

Built-in:

```py
# should be -11.28443261177375
>>> (-2967000000)**(1/9)
(10.603898055039648+3.8595032592277083j)
```

NumPy:

```py
# should be -11.28443261177375
>>> np.pow(-2967000000, 1/9)
nan
```

Is there an efficient way using NumPy or a built-in method to force Python to use the negative Real solution? I would like to avoid writing a function to satisfy this need if possible. I am currently using `np.sign(x)*abs(x)**(1/n)`. Is there any improvement that I can make?

Comment: I think your method is ok, just use vectorizing and `np.abs` instead of `abs`

Comment: Are you performing this operation on numpy arrays or just individual numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy n-th odd root including negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50491326/numpy-n-th-odd-root-including-negative-values)

Comment: @Nin17 It is adjacent but it doesn't answer the question. I was specifically looking for either a built-in function or numpy implementation. I wanted to avoid defining a function.

Comment: @jared to be precise, I am passing this operation through df.apply() to a Dataframe of floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran some tests trying different methods to see which would be the fastest.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame({"nums": np.arange(-2967000000, 100, 10000, dtype=float)})


def method1(df=df, n=1/9):
    return df["nums"].apply(lambda x: np.sign(x)*np.abs(x)**n)


def method2(df=df, n=1/9):
    return df["nums"].apply(lambda x: np.sign(x)*np.power(np.abs(x), n))


def method3(df=df, n=1/9):
    return df["nums"].apply(lambda x: math.copysign(x, abs(x)**n))


def method4(df=df, n=1/9):
    x = df["nums"]
    return pd.Series(np.sign(x)*np.abs(x)**n)


def method5(df=df, n=1/9):
    x = df["nums"]
    return pd.Series(np.sign(x)*np.power(np.abs(x), n))


methods = [method1, method2, method3, method4, method5]

N = 7
for method in methods:
    print(method.__name__, timeit.timeit(method, number=N)/N)
```

Output:

```py
method1 0.6219473714285674
method2 0.8631320142857086
method3 0.13383357142856767
method4 0.011573042857110392
method5 0.011473671428575472
```

So, using the numpy functions directly on the pandas Series (avoiding `apply`) is the fastest. This makes sense because numpy is fast when working with arrays. The next fastest is using the math library with `apply`, which is consistent with what I just said about numpy being fast with arrays. The slowest methods were the numpy methods used with `apply`, since that essentially loops through the data frame; you shouldn't use numpy when looping.

Comment: Interesting insights. Thank you